# Pasar función en View a clase ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy intentando pasar una función de un View a una clase ObservableObject, he probado en la clase a poner @EnvironmentObject pero no me deja.

Este es el view donde tengo una extensión con la función que quiero que en la otra clase:

```
extension View {
func getRect()->CGRect{
    return UIScreen.main.bounds
}

func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController {
    guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
        return .init()
    }
    
    guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
        return .init()
    }
    
    return root
}
```

}

Y esta es la clase AuthViewModel que es donde quiero ver la función que tengo en el view (esto es lo que he probado y no me deja):

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Environment var signInView: SignInView

func loginGoogle(){
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

    // Create Google Sign In configuration object.
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, **presenting: getRootViewController**()) {
        [self] user, err in
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Estás usando MVVM? En esta clase `AuthViewModel`, en dónde llamas a `getRect()` o `getRootViewController`?

Comment: @Bicho la llamo en la función func loginGoogle(){
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

        // Create Google Sign In configuration object.
        let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) {
            [self] user, err in

Comment: Ya lo tienes editado Bicho, en esa función es donde esta el getRootViewController que quiero llamar desde el View

Comment: Debería ser `signInView.getRootViewController()` y la etiqueta correcta `SwiftUI`.

Comment: Si,  pongo signInView pero esta forma de declararlo es correcta? Environment var signInView: SignInView o debería de ser EnvironmentObject var signInView: SignInView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay unos errores básicos en tu código.

Primero, los SwiftUI wrappers solo deben de ser usados en `struct` q son una SwiftUI `View`. Ahorita lo tienes incluido en una `class`. Con esto vas a ver el valor inicial pero los siguientes valores van a ser inconsistentes. La única excepción es `@Published`.

Segundo, usar el root view controller no es documentado y Apple ha desestabilizado esta forma de accesar `UIKit` cada ano desde q empezó SwiftUI. Es mejor presentar en un `UIViewController` directamente.

Tambien si usas el root view para presentar te podes encontrar con problemas presentando cosas porq `View`s como `.sheet` y `.popover` usan esa misma posición.

Ahora para solucionar tu problema. Debes de usar la implementación q usa google en su muestra lo mas possible. Como sabes Google usa UIKit entonces haces mínimas conexiones con SwiftUI para q funcione.

```
import SwiftUI
struct AuthView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(vm.authStatus.rawValue)
            Button("login", action: {
                vm.login()
            })
            //You might have to play with the position of this.
            AuthScreenView_UI(viewModel: vm).frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}
//Aqui es donde vas a poner la information q necesites porq UIKit y SwiftUI van a tener accesso a la misma information
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject, MiAuthViewModelProtocol{
    ///referencia a UIKit
    var uiViewController: MiAuthViewControllerProtocol? = nil
    
    @Published var authStatus: AuthStatus = .unknown
    //MARK: MiAuthViewModelProtocol
    func login() {
        print(#function)
        uiViewController?.login()
    }
    func logout() {
        print(#function)
        uiViewController?.logout()
    }
    func setAuthStatus(authStatus: AuthStatus) {
        print(#function)
        self.authStatus = authStatus
    }
    
    
}
//Esta estructura hace compatible el UIViewController de google con SwiftUI
struct AuthScreenView_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some AuthScreenViewController {
        print(#function)
        return AuthScreenViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
//Aqui vas a poner el codigo de muestra de Google
//https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in
//Yo no tengo una mustra con este framework ahorita pero sige los pasos indicados
class AuthScreenViewController: UIViewController, MiAuthViewControllerProtocol {
    ///referencia a SwiftUI
    var viewModel: MiAuthViewModelProtocol
    
    init(viewModel: MiAuthViewModelProtocol) {
        print(#function)
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .main)
        //Conneccion entre UIKit y SwiftUI
        self.viewModel.uiViewController = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(#function)
        viewModel.setAuthStatus(authStatus: .initialized)
    }
    //MARK: MiAuthViewControllerProtocol
    func login() {
        print(#function)
        viewModel.setAuthStatus(authStatus: .loggingIn)
        //Los pasos de la seccion 3.2 de la guia van aqui.
    }
    func logout() {
        print(#function)
        viewModel.setAuthStatus(authStatus: .loggingOut)
        //Los pasos de la seccion 4.2 de la guia van aqui.
    }
}
//Protocolos no son necesarioes pero de ayudan a reusar el codigo y ver como todo se connecta
//Si quieres mas funciones agregalas aqui primero para q las puedas implementar en el ViewModel y el UIViewController
protocol MiAuthViewModelProtocol{
    ///Referencia al google view controller
    var uiViewController: MiAuthViewControllerProtocol? { get set }
    
    ///Le dice al viewController que login
    func login()
    ///Le dice al viewController que logout
    func logout()
    ///Sets the Ad Status
    func setAuthStatus(authStatus: AuthStatus)
}
protocol MiAuthViewControllerProtocol: UIViewController{
    ///Referencia al  SwiftUI ViewModel
    var viewModel: MiAuthViewModelProtocol { get set }
    ///Le dice a Google que login
    func login()
    ///Le dice a Google que  logout
    func logout()
}
enum AuthStatus: String{
    case initialized
    case loggingIn
    case loggingOut
    case unknown
    case error
}

struct AuthViewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AuthView()
    }
}
```